# How can I handle HTTP request with react front-end and flask back-end

Tags: reactjs, flask, pycharm, httprequest

I am building a web application using flask framework for my back-end and my front-end in react. I would like to connect these two using `http` request but I have no clue on where to start. I am using **PyCharm IDE** for both front and back end.

I have looked into `react-http-request` library but I didn't understand it.

I want to be able to send strings from my front-end to my back-end and send `json` files from back-end to front-end.

Comment: You can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) . It is a Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Native fetch() function of the browser can do that for you.

Use it like this:

```
fetch('http://your.server.domain/api/endpoint', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
}).then((res) => {
  return res.json();
}).then((json) => {
  // this is your json data from your server
  console.log(json);
});
```